# Coffeescript Looping Function

Tags: sql, loops, coffeescript

I am trying to get this block of code to loop 7 times in coffeescript

```
, round(sum(case when b.data_type='fringe' and b.rp=201802  and b.tpd<=b.rp 
then b.bcws else 0 end),0) as bcwsFringe
, round(sum(case when b.data_type='fringe' and b.rp=201802  
and b.tpd<=b.rp then b.bcwp else 0 end),0) as bcwpFringe
, round(sum(case when b.data_type='fringe' and b.rp=201802  and b.tpd<=b.rp 
then b.acwp else 0 end),0) as acwpFringe
```

I was wondering if anyone could provide some insight?

Comment: http://coffeescript.org/#loops

Comment: use an iterator variable